# How to print the text of functions, variable names, closures, etc. at runtime?

Tags: rust

Let's say I have a struct as follows:

```
struct Abc {
  a: i32,
  b: fn(i32) -> bool
}
```

where `a` is just a stored value and `b` is a user-supplied closure that checks some condition upon `a`. If the condition evaluates to false at some point, I want to `panic!` and print some debug information about what went wrong.

For example, if I set `b` to be `|x| x < 10`, it's fairly easy to assert upon result of `b(a)`, but if the assertion fails the output looks something like:

```
panicked at 'assertion failed: (self.b)(self.a)'
```

which isn't very helpful. What I'd like to be able to print is something like:

```
panicked at 'Abc condiditon failed: x < 10'
```

---

Basically, is there some way to get the 'text' of some code for debug message purposes? Getting it just as a string is enough, I don't need anything easily parseable. I suspect it'll involve some macro trickery if it's possible at all, but I wouldn't know where to begin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the original code is not normally preserved in the binary in Rust, you can indeed build this using a macro:

```rust
struct LambdaAndText(fn(i32) -> bool, &'static str);

impl LambdaAndText {
    fn call(&self, arg: i32) {
        assert!((self.0)(arg), "Abc condiditon failed: {}", self.1);
    }
}

macro_rules! lambda_and_text {
    (|$p:pat| $e:expr) => {
        LambdaAndText(|$p| $e, stringify!($e))
    };
}

fn main() {
    let l = lambda_and_text!(|x| x < 10);

    l.call(5);
    l.call(42);
}
```

[This prints `thread 'main' panicked at 'Abc condiditon failed: x < 10', src/main.rs:5:9` as expected](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fcbe842a6bd08d1338022359e4062234).

Comment: Actually, is there a way to do this when the closure is already stored in a variable? E.g. `let l = |x| x < 10; let s = lambda_and_text!(l);`? This would make my code much neater but isn't strictly necessary to solve the underlying problem

Comment: No, this relies on the `stringify!` macro, which can't get a string out of variables. It only gives a string of whatever is passed to it as-it.